# How can I keep the value that I set so I can return it? Android

Tags: java, android

That's the best title I could come up with but my problem is a little hard to explain without just looking at the code. I've added some comments to explain what is going on. Here is my code:

```
private Movie APICallTwo(final String ID)
    {
        Movie found;//want to return this

        OkHttpClient client2 = new OkHttpClient();
        String urlforID = "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?i=" + ID + "&r=json";
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlforID)
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "")//deleted the key for obvious reasons
                .build();
        client2.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
            {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String title = "";
                    String year = "";
                    String rated = "";
                    String released = "";
                    String runtime = "";
                    String genre = "";
                    String director = "";
                    String writer = "";
                    String actors = "";
                    String plot = "";
                    String imdbID = "";
                    String production = "";

                    String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    try
                    {
                        myObj = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try
                    {    
                        title = myObj.getString("Title");
                        year = myObj.getString("Year");
                        rated = myObj.getString("Rated");
                        released = myObj.getString("Released");
                        runtime = myObj.getString("Runtime");
                        genre = myObj.getString("Genre");
                        director = myObj.getString("Director");
                        writer = myObj.getString("Writer");
                        actors = myObj.getString("Actors");
                        plot = myObj.getString("Plot");
                        imdbID = myObj.getString("imdbID");

                        try//not all movies have production companies listen on IMDb
                        {
                            production = myObj.getString("Production");
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            production = "N/A";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    test = new Movie(title, year, rated, released, runtime, genre, director, writer, actors, plot, imdbID, production);//test is declared as "Movie test" up in the main

//                    Log.d("in ApiCall2", "The Details for: " + ID + " are: \n" + test.printMovie());//this check works, it returns what is in test properly
                }
            }

        });
        found = test;
                            Log.d("in ApiCall2", "The Details for: " + ID + " are: \n" + found.printMovie());//this check doesn't work, says that test is null

        detailLatch.countDown();
        return found;
    }
```

How can I get it so that I keep the information that is grabbed and pass it back to where it was called? I know that when something is declared in a loop or another function that gets forgotten when it leaves that function but that doesn't make sense here. I have no other ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know that creating a network call is Asynchronous. So returning a value from an Asynchronous function to your activity/fragment whatever the view is, you need to create a proper callback which be triggered once the response is fetched.

**STEP 1:** Create an interface

```
interface NetworkCallback{
    void onNetworkResponse(Movie movie); //There could be any type of object you want to return.
}
```

**STEP 2:** Pass NetworkCallback reference to you Asynchronous function

```
private void fetchMovie(final String ID,NetworkCallback networkCallback) {
        Movie found;//want to return this

        OkHttpClient client2=new OkHttpClient();
        String urlforID="https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?i="+ID+"&r=json";
        final Request request=new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlforID)
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host","movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key","")//deleted the key for obvious reasons
                .build();
        client2.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call,IOException e)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call,Response response)throws IOException
            {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String title="";
                    String year="";
                    String rated="";
                    String released="";
                    String runtime="";
                    String genre="";
                    String director="";
                    String writer="";
                    String actors="";
                    String plot="";
                    String imdbID="";
                    String production="";

                    String myResponse=response.body().string();
                    try
                    {
                        myObj=new JSONObject(myResponse);
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        title=myObj.getString("Title");
                        year=myObj.getString("Year");
                        rated=myObj.getString("Rated");
                        released=myObj.getString("Released");
                        runtime=myObj.getString("Runtime");
                        genre=myObj.getString("Genre");
                        director=myObj.getString("Director");
                        writer=myObj.getString("Writer");
                        actors=myObj.getString("Actors");
                        plot=myObj.getString("Plot");
                        imdbID=myObj.getString("imdbID");

                        try//not all movies have production companies listen on IMDb
                        {
                            production=myObj.getString("Production");
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e)
                        {
                            production="N/A";
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Movie movie =new Movie(title,year,rated,released,runtime,genre,director,writer,actors,plot,imdbID,production);//test is declared as "Movie test" up in the main

                    networkCallback.onNetworkResponse(movie);
//                    Log.d("in ApiCall2", "The Details for: " + ID + " are: \n" + test.printMovie());//this check works, it returns what is in test properly
                }
            }

        });
        //Log.d("in ApiCall2","The Details for: "+ID+" are: \n"+found.printMovie());//this check doesn't work, says that test is null

       // detailLatch.countDown();
    }
```

**STEP 3:** Call `fetchMovie` from activity/fragment. And update UI inside onNetworkResponse

```
    private void fetchMovie(){
        APICallTwo("YOUR_ID", new NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onNetworkResponse(Movie movie) {
                //NOW YOU RECEIVED YOUR FAVORITE MOVIE INFO
                //UPDATE YOUR UI HERE
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i made [this template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android) for questions like these, feel free to refer to it in future if you want something to copy quickly :)

Comment: @JunaidKhan Would this still work if I want to save the value into an array? Like would MovieArray[i] = movie work?

Comment: Yes, In that just change the onNetworkResponse method perameter type to array of movies.

Comment: You can make the callback more generic by using the concept generics.